# блок подпунктов меню на высоту экрана

Tags: html, css

Есть сайдбар. При наведении курсора на основной пункт, появляется блок с подпунктом, но его высота зависит от высоты контента. Не могу понять, как сделать высоту блока на высоту экрана, как на фото. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.main {
  font-family: PT Sans;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #38618C;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  z-index: 1;
  user-select: none;
}

.main_menu_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main_menu_content_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  height: 700px;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

.main_menu_content_list a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #D7DFE8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content_list_submenu {
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: #F0F6F8;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  transition: all linear 0.1s 0s;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.main_menu_content_list>li.main_menu_content_list_arrow>a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 10px;
  border-color: transparent #F0F6F8 transparent transparent;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list>li.main_menu_content_list_arrow:hover>a:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover .content_list_submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover>.content_list_submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #38618C;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:hover {
  color: #38618C;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:active {
  color: #FF5964;
}

.main_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main_menu">
    <div class="main_menu_content">
      <ul class="main_menu_content_list">
        <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow">
          <a href="">
            <div class="main_menu_content_list_int"></div>Интернет
          </a>
          <div>
            <div class="content_list_submenu">
              <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Дополнительные услуги</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Настройка соединения</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Документы</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow">
          <a href="">
            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tv"></div>Телевидение
          </a>
          <div class="content_list_submenu">
            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
              <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Новости</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Акции</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Аналоговое ТВ</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Оборудование</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Настройка каналов</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Документы</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow">
          <a href="/content/video.html">
            <div class="main_menu_content_list_video"></div>Видеонаблюдение,<br>домофон
          </a>
          <div class="content_list_submenu">
            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
              <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Обслуживание</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Установка</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Заявка на ремонт</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/content/rek.html">
            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tvr"></div>ТВ Реклама
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">
            <div class="main_menu_content_list_intb"></div>Интернет для бизнеса
          </a>
        </li>
        <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_block">
          <li><a href="">Оплата</a></li>
          <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
        </div>
        <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow">
          <a href="">
            <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_account"></div>Личный кабинет
          </a>
          <div class="content_list_submenu">
            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
              <li><a href="">Интернет</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Телевидение</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main_content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: height: 100vh обычно помогает. Или, если это абсолютно спозиционированный объект, можно сделать top: 0; bottom: 0 (при условии, что релативный родитель сам занимает всю высоту экрана)

Comment: так тоже делал. Не получается ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.main {
  font-family: PT Sans;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #38618c;
  z-index: 1;
  user-select: none;
}

.main_menu_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main_menu_content_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  height: 700px;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #d7dfe8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content_list_submenu {
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: #f0f6f8;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  transition: all linear 0.1s 0s;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.main_menu_content_list > li.main_menu_content_list_arrow > a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 10px;
  border-color: transparent #f0f6f8 transparent transparent;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list > li.main_menu_content_list_arrow:hover > a:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover .content_list_submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover > .content_list_submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #38618c;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:hover {
  color: #38618c;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:active {
  color: #ff5964;
}

.main_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: [Код на codepen](https://codepen.io/Crook/pen/KKVmXNB)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но суть задачи заключалась в том, что бы подпункты с выезжающего блока оставались абсолютно по центру, относительно родителя

Comment: ну тогда, можете либо центровать их в ручную, либо же не использовать этот код, а просто подставить псевдо елемент под низ на всю высоту родительского елемента

Comment: центрировал с помощью rem. Все нормально, но как только стоит начать "играться" с размерами браузера, всё центрирование нарушается. Я решил этот вопрос таким путем: классу ".main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup" я установил margin "100vh 0 100vh 0". И все норм.